# How to interpret the expression "of any city" in this sentence?

Tags: phrases

([thinkquest](http://library.thinkquest.org/C003133/data/uk/page3.htm))

> London itself is a living museum, with more than 2,000 years of history and culture. But it also boasts one of the greatest concentrations of significant museums (more than 100) **of any city** in the world.

In the second sentence, how to interpret the expression "of any city"? Does it refer to **"museums of almost every city in the world"** or "**museums that cannot be compared by any city in the world**"? Why? It seems that I cannot find a proper explanation for either interpretation. In other words, I even think this sentence is not correct. Can anyone tell me which expression or word in the sentence is around with the expression "*of any city*"?

Comment: Always cite the source.

Comment: I believe the sentence is ambiguous. It can be interpreted as "one of the greatest concentrations of [significant museums of any city] in the world", or "one of [the greatest concentrations [of significant museums] of any city in the world]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it means that London has the  greatest concentrations of significant museums (more than 100) **as compared to any/all other cities of the world**.

It refers to the `concentration of significant museums that cannot be compared by any city of the world`.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly normal. It is effectively an intensifier, and may be omitted without greatly changing the sense.

The analytic meaning is, as tMJ indicated, something like "comparing the concentration of museums in every city in the world, London has one of the greatest concentrations".